# Growth rate of formula

Tags: combinatorics

I have formula: $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$
I am wondering what is growth rate of it. Can I say that it grows exponentially with m and n? Or maybe this is different growth rate?
Greetings,
Rnd

Comment: If you fix $n$, the expression is in fact a degree $n$ polynomial in the variable $m$; $$\frac{(m+n)!}{m!\,n!}=\frac{m+1}{1}\frac{m+2}{2}\cdots\frac{m+n}{n}= \frac{m^n}{n!} + {\cal O}(m^{n-1}).$$ However if you let $n$ and $m$ vary together in some specified way, you can obtain different levels of growth. For instance, if $n=m$, then the growth rate is exponential as $$\frac{(n+n)!}{n!\,n!}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$ (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient.)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a very close approximation for $n=m$:
$$
n!n!=(n!)^2 \approx \frac{n^2n}{e^2n} 2 \pi n\\
(2n)! \approx \frac{(2n)^{2n}}{e^{2n}}2 \sqrt{\pi n}
$$
Dividing $(2n)!$ through $n!^2$you get that 
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2} \approx \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$